# Convert node.js HTTP response function (using "request" library) to use streams

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, httprequest

I'm using the [request library](https://github.com/request/request) in node.js, which downloads an HTML body response, but does so in chunks. Currently I'm just concatenating them into a `dataChunks` variable and using a hacked-together test to see when it's all downloaded. However, I've skim-read the [Stream Handbook](https://github.com/substack/stream-handbook), and this seems like a case where it might be appropriate to use a stream to get the data chunks. I don't fully understand how I'd do this though, so would appreciate any help. The relevant code is below:

```
var dataChunks = "";

request.get({ url: baseUrl + path })
            .on("error", function(err) { throw new Error(err); })
            .on("response", function(res) {
                if (res.statusCode === 200) {
                    res.on("data", function(data) {
                        var dataString, dt;

                        dataChunks += (dataString = data.toString());

                        if ((dt = dataString.slice(-100).trimRight()).lastIndexOf("</html>") === dt.length - 7) {
                            // do stuff with dataChunks
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a stream for that.  From the request Readme:

```
var request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
 } 
})
```

Stream example:

```
request('http://google.com/doodle.png').pipe(fs.createWriteStream('doodle.png'))
```

Comment: Okay, I know I can do it like that and just receive the response all at once (which would be easiest), but are there not advantages to streaming the data as it comes in? Or would there only be advantages if you wanted to use/display the chunks individually?

Comment: See the second example for a stream.  There are advantages, but not for just retrieving the body of a normal page to show in thr console.  Streaming to a file as per example is probably an advantage though especially if its a large file.